# Custom HTML5 video controlls - FULLSCREEN

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, video

I have got a HTML5 video tag on my page, there you can toggle fullscreen. When I'm pressing my fullscreen button, it's ok. Video is going on fullscreen.

I'm initiating fullscreen by:

```
var mediaElement = document.getElementById('videoAbout');
var iOS = /iPad|iPhone|iPod/.test(navigator.userAgent) && !window.MSStream;
if(iOS) {
    mediaElement.webkitEnterFullscreen();
    mediaElement.enterFullscreen();
}
else {
    if(mediaElement.requestFullScreen) {
        mediaElement.requestFullScreen();
    }
    else if(mediaElement.webkitRequestFullScreen) {
        mediaElement.webkitRequestFullScreen();
    }
    else if(mediaElement.mozRequestFullScreen) {
        mediaElement.mozRequestFullScreen();
    }
    else if(mediaElement.msRequestFullScreen) {
        mediaElement.mozRequestFullScreen();
    } 
}
```

To exit from fullscreen i was trying to use:

```
var mediaElement = document.getElementById('videoAbout');
var iOS = /iPad|iPhone|iPod/.test(navigator.userAgent) && !window.MSStream;
if(iOS) {
    mediaElement.webkitEnterFullscreen();
    mediaElement.enterFullscreen();
}
else {
    if(mediaElement.requestFullScreen) {
        mediaElement.exitFullScreen();
    }
    else if(mediaElement.webkitRequestFullScreen) {
        mediaElement.webkitExitFullScreen();
    }
    else if(mediaElement.mozRequestFullScreen) {
        mediaElement.mozExitFullScreen();
    }
    else if(mediaElement.msRequestFullScreen) {
        mediaElement.mozExitFullScreen();
    } 
}
```

Same with `CancelFullScreen()`, I was trying to add this to else if statement everything is not working. Console says that the function is not exists (`CancelFullScreen` or `ExitFullScreen`).

So here is my question, how to exit from fullscreen HTML5 video? I prefer not to use plugins.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ExitFullScreen not working + anyway to keyboard press on button click?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22725607/exitfullscreen-not-working-anyway-to-keyboard-press-on-button-click)

Comment: You missunderstand, console says that `document.exitFullScreen()` is not a function... :(

Comment: Why do you prefer not to use plugins? If for learning purposes I can understand but for production [screenfull](https://www.npmjs.com/package/screenfull) does what you want.

Anyway, I suggest you look at the screenfull source code exit function.

Comment: A jsFiddle of this would be useful.

Comment: I don't think is going to work in Internet Explorer (IE). IE doesn't have full support. So `if (mediaElement.msRequestFullScreen)` doesn't work you can still use `mediaElement.msRequestFullScreen();` but you'll need another way to determine IE. This well only work in IE 11. Anything below well not. FYI.

Comment: @JohnEhrmantraut in your sample code you're not calling ``document.exitFullScreen()``, you're calling ``mediaElement.exitFullScreen();``. Have you tried it with ``document``?

Comment: I've tested this code. Can it didn't work for me either no errors in console. I did both `mediaElement` and `document`. Goes full screen and can't leave full screen.

Comment: Hey look at the answer by @IliaRostovtsev on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19357854/html5-exiting-video-fullscreen

Comment: thanks guys! i finally used screenfull plugin